# Assign a button on the bottom of a ListView (and handling its click events)

Tags: android, listview

As the title said, I want to add a button on the bottom of my `ListView` and handle its click event by setting an `onClickListener` to it. This should really be a simple task, but I've been trying for quite awhile with no results at all.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    mLvWaybillItemList = (ListView) mWizardPagerAdapter.getShipmentItemsView().findViewById(R.id.lv_items);
    mLvWaybillItemList.setEmptyView(mWizardPagerAdapter.getShipmentItemsView().findViewById(R.id.empty_view));

    View footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.component_waybill_item_stub_list_footer, null);
    mLvWaybillItemList.addFooterView(footerView);

    mBtAddItemListFooter = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.bt_create);
    mBtAddItemListFooter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPresenter.onItemAdditionRequest();
        }
    });

    ...

}
```

That code unfortunately always gives me a `NullPointerException`, saying that `mBtAddItemListFooter` is `null`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

What's exactly going on here? Why can't I access `mBtAddItemListFooter`?

Comment: Where is declared and initialized `mPresenter`?

Comment: Somewhere above that piece of code (still within `onCreate()`) I fail to see why would this matters though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are not adding an adapter to the List view.
The `addFooterView(footerView)` will expect atleast 1 item to be present in the listview.

Comment: I do assign an adapter, albeit later in the process. And if I'm not trying to gain access to the aforementioned button, this would all work. I can even see said button live in my device. Right until I tried to do this `mBtAddItemListFooter = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.bt_create);`. With that said, shouldn't adapter not be a problem here?

Comment: I've tried to move the code to *after* I set an adapter but still, no luck.